# MySQL searching non-english characters - o = ø, etc

Tags: mysql, collation

I have my mySQL collation set to utf8_general_ci and despite the fact that my searches are diacritical-insensitive, ie LIKE 'test' returns 'tést', some searches which I would like to work fail, in particular LIKE 'host' will NOT return 'høst'.

Two questions: Is there a table that will show which characters are equivalent for a particular collation? Is there a way to set two characters as equivalents in mySQL as an override?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer for first question you can referance [collation-charts.org](http://collation-charts.org/mysql60/by-charset.shtml). It's kind of a pain because you will need to search each collation by hand, but it'll show you how they stack.

The relevant section in the MySQL manual can also be found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html).

As far as your second question, I'm not sure if you can do an explicit override for a particular character; however you can create your own custom character set if you wish.

You can read about creating custom collations [from the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-collation.html).

Comment: Tons of very helpful information, thank you. I don't understand exactly why there are multiple collation sets for utf8_general and utf8_unicode, but I am sure the info is in there. It certainly does confirm, though, that Ø is not considered a diacritical of O, so I have to make a special str_replace in my php codeif I want them to return as such. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, don't forget to mark the question as answered if you feel that I have adequately answered your questions.